# how to create a url for jdbc(google app script) with sqlite uploaded in google drive

Tags: google-apps-script

The sqlite file have been upload to google drive. But how can I use the JDBC to connect it?

```
  var conCom = 'jdbc:sqlite';
  var conCom2 = "a.sqlite";
  conCom = conCom + ':' + conCom2;
  var connection = Jdbc.getConnection(conCom);
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script only [supports](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc) JDBC connections to MySQL, Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server and Google Cloud SQL. You can log a request for features at the [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).